# INTO a reserved keyword cannot be used as an identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a script in oracle to capture a value of existing field into a variable and then use that value for the insert statements. I getting error INTO a reserved keyword cannot be used as an identifier at this line of code

```
SELECT INTO act_id8   FROM INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION  where name like 'ResearchPanel';
```

Script

```
declare

  act_id8  number;


  begin 

    SELECT INTO act_id8   FROM INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION  where name like 'ResearchPanel';


    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6012,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6000,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6001,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6002,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6003,act_id8,15);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6004,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6005,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6006,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6015,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(1005,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(1006,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6011,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6079,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6080,act_id8,15);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(1004,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6041,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(1007,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6007,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6025,act_id8,5);
    INSERT INTO INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ROLE_ACTION(ROLE_ID,ACTION_ID,PERMISSION_ID) VALUES(6016,act_id8,5);


commit; 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the name of the field you wish to select. You wrote

```
SELECT INTO act_id8   FROM INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION  where name like 'ResearchPanel';
```

You should write something like

```
SELECT some_field INTO act_id8   FROM INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION  where name like 'ResearchPanel';
```

Replace `some_field` with the name of the field in INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION which you wish to retrieve and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
SELECT INTO act_id8   FROM INSIGHT.INSIGHT_MVC_ACTION ...
      ^
      |
select what exactly into act_id8 variable? That's missing!
```